# Discrepancy in gas prices in ENS

Tags: gas, gas-price, gas-estimate, ens

I'm a bit confused, I'm trying to buy a domain name in https://ens.domains/ and the price is extremely high for a domain name, it's about $150. Most of that price comes from gas fees. The confusing thing is that ens tells me the following
`Estimated Total (Price + Gas). The gas price is based at 130 Gwei` whereas in https://ethgasstation.info/ the gas price is 83. So it's 130 in ens and 83 in ethgasstation. Is that correct? Why ENS would consider a higher price for gas?
Also, is there a way to see in ENS how is that estimated total calculated?

Comment: i have this same confusion. anyone? seems like ens is three transactions total and it's adding those?

Answer (score 0):

8 mos. old, but in case someone still wonders the answer..

Different transactions use different amounts of gas. The 83 is just the base GWEI for ETH transfers, which are the most simple trips of transaction i believe.

Comment: The question refers to the quoted gas price, not the gas limit required for transaction execution.